# How in CouchDB get GET parameter

Tags: couchdb

I need get GET (or other) parameter in my CouchDB map() function.

P.S. I want search by polygon and for this i need to have list of points and compare with documents position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access any parameters in your map function.  The only thing map functions do is **output** key/value pairs.  You can then limit the rows returned based on either a single key (`key`), a list of multiple keys (`keys`), or a range of keys (`startKey` and/or `endKey`).  See more in [the docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options).

Comment: ok, what way are you recommend? I'm not sure is filtering on PHP side is correct.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some of your data.

Comment: I shoud search by [Date] or/and [Tags] or/and [Position on map].